# Shopware 6 get category name from store-api endpoint

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I use endpoint `/store-api/checkout/order` is it possible to get from this endpoint category name? Now I can only reach out category ids.

Comment: How are you calling this endpoint? You might be able to add associations but I fear that might not be possible in the store-api - so you would need to fetch the category names separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the endpoint you are using, detailed category info cannot be retrieved. A secondary call will be necessary.

P.S. I am not even sure how you are getting `categoryId`'s here. It's not in the documentation.

Ref: https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/a020d67a79ed0-create-an-order-from-a-cart